# Find real numbers satisfying some conditions of rational dependance

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

> Does there exist $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_4\in\mathbb R$ such that
>
> $$\forall (\alpha,\beta)\in\mathbb Q^2\setminus\{0,0\},\quad \begin{cases}\dim_{\mathbb Q}(\alpha \xi_1+\beta\xi_3,\,\alpha\xi_2+\beta\xi_4)= 2 \\ \dim_{\mathbb Q}(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4,\xi_1\xi_4-\xi_2\xi_3)\leqslant 2\quad ?\end{cases}$$

I believe the answer to be *negative*, but I have no idea in how to prove such a result isn't true.

I have try to search many examples (while I still have hoped for it to be true), but non of those seem to work for various reasons. For instance, I searched quite a lot something like: $\xi_i=a_i\xi+b_i\xi^2$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,4\}$, but it was unsuccessful.

Any progress regarding this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: The first condition certainly cannot hold when $\alpha=\beta=0$.

Comment: Also,as $\alpha\xi_1+\beta\xi_3$ and $\alpha\xi_2+\beta\xi_4$ are in the span of $\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4,\xi_1\xi_4-\xi_2\xi_3$, the $\le2$ can be replaced with $=2$ or with $\xi_1\xi_4-\xi_2\xi_3\in\Bbb Q[\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4]$.

Comment: @user1551 You are right, sorry for the typo...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes indeed. Do you think I should add your remark to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Without some restrictions the answer in the upper case is clearly negative: just take $\;\alpha=\beta=0\;$, and thus the overall answer is *no* .

Comment: You are right, sorry for the typo, I'll edit.